# Is a Preposition Needed in the Sentence: 我只认识一个人有新冠状病毒

Tags: sentence-structure

If 我只认识一个人 is a complete sentence, and I want to express the information that this is the one person that I know who has COVID, would I need a preposition between 人 and 有? If a preposition is needed then why. If otherwise, then why not?

Comment: It's fine to me. Nothing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean "relative pronoun" rather than "preposition"?

It's better this way:
我只认识一个有新冠状病毒的人

Comment: Thank you a lot.